# Mouse Cursor Disappeared, Ubuntu 18

Tags: mouse

I am running Ubuntu 18, yesterday the mouse cursor suddenly disappeared. I tried a lot of ways to fix it, but it never worked. Today, I reinstalled the Ubuntu 18, and the mouse cursor is back. After running the updates in the first start-up, the mouse cursor is gone again. Is there any advice for this case. It is very frustrating... Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Please be specific with your Ubuntu release.  Ubuntu Core 18 does not have a GUI given it's intended for IoT appliances or devices which are usually used headless.  Server and Desktop releases of Ubuntu use *year.month* format.

Comment: Thank you, guiverc. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 Desktop. The mouse cursor was not an issue at all, until very recently. When I reinstall it, the cursor showed up, but it will disappear after a (sudo apt-get update).